# How to display Legend with seaborn.kdeplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend

I have been trying add the Legend to my code below.
It should have worked when I add the "Label". But it just won't show, not sure what I did wrong.

## Packages Used

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.stats as stats
from scipy.stats import kruskal
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

Df1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\pc admin\Desktop\SUTD Programming\Data Wrangling\Personal Assigment\IBM Data.csv", header=0)


plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
plt.style.use('seaborn-colorblind')
plt.grid(True, alpha=0.5)
sns.kdeplot(Df1.loc[Df1['Attrition'] == 'No', 'JobSatisfaction'], **label = "Previous-Employee"**)
sns.kdeplot(Df1.loc[Df1['Attrition'] == 'Yes', 'JobSatisfaction'], **label ="Current-Employees"**)
plt.xlabel('JobSatisfaction')
plt.xlim(left=0)
plt.ylabel('Density')
plt.title('Distance From Home Distribution in Percent by Attrition Status');
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to call the `.legend()` method of your Axes object. The plotting functions of seaborn return the reference to the Axes directly which is handy. See the documentation of [`sns.kdeplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html)

```
ax = sns.kdeplot(...)
ax.legend(loc="upper right")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.stats as stats
from scipy.stats import kruskal
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

import matplotlib.patches as mpatches


Df1 = pd.r`enter code here`ead_csv(
r"C:\Users\pc admin\Desktop\SUTD Programming\Data 
Wrangling\Personal Assigment\IBM Data.csv", header=0)


plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))
plt.style.use('seaborn-colorblind')
plt.grid(True, alpha=0.5)
sns.kdeplot(Df1.loc[Df1['Attrition'] == 'No', 
'JobSatisfaction'], **label="Previous-Employee"**)
 sns.kdeplot(Df1.loc[Df1['Attrition'] == 'Yes', 
'JobSatisfaction'], **label="Current-Employees"**)
plt.xlabel('JobSatisfaction')
plt.xlim(left=0)
plt.ylabel('Density')
plt.title('Distance From Home Distribution in Percent 
by Attrition Status')

handles = [mpatches.Patch(facecolor=plt.cm.Reds(100), 
label="Active Employee"),
       mpatches.Patch(facecolor=plt.cm.Blues(100), 
label="Ex employee")]
plt.legend(handles=handles)
# chose whatever colour you want hope thats help you 
#out :)
#legends was deprecated in python 3 if you have object 
of #sns.kdeplot
```